# all Values are not inserted in database

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jakarta-ee

I have a excel file with more than `20000 row`s, which has large amount of data and the data from this file is inserted into database through a java Program.

Whenever I run the file, some of the values are skipped and are not inserted into database.

Can anyone explain why is this so ?

Also, after inserting more than 300 values,**`ORA-00933`: SQL command not properly ended exception is thrown.**

Comment: Are you doing batch insert or inserting one row at a time? Also, post the exception stacktrace and portion of the code that throws the exception to better understand what your code is doing.

Comment: check you schema, check if its correct and is same in which you need to insert values..

Comment: I am using addBatch method.

Comment: Some of The values should be having single quotes and they are failing. Can you please show how you frame your insert statement, so that we can correct it.

Comment: rs=ss.executeQuery("select keyword,ata_code,ac_model from ata_keywords where keyword='"+a1Va2+"'");

Comment: The above is my insert statement @MaheswaranRavisankar

Comment: @AmrenduPandey This is your `SELECT` statement only.. how about your `INSERT` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For security reasons (and others as well) you should never just concatenate input into a statement without properly escaping the input.

Use a prepared statement instead which would enable the database or driver to take care of escaping special charaters in your input. Without escaping you could end up with invalid or even harmful queries.

Example:

```
String a1Va2 = "';DROP table ata_keywords;'";

rs=ss.executeQuery("select keyword,ata_code,ac_model from ata_keywords where keyword='"+a1Va2+"'");
```

This would result in two queries:

```
select keyword,ata_code,ac_model from ata_keywords where keyword='';
DROP table ata_keywords; //Ooops
'' //the last bit is ignored
```

The exception you're getting indicates that some input contains a sequence that results in an invalid query.

Comment: Oracle won't execute multiple statements like that via JDBC - the `;` statement separator will cause an 'invalid character' error. But using a prepared statement is still better, and the OP's `insert` issue is likely to be similar.

Comment: @AlexPoole yes, that's what I wanted to say: the OP's issue is most likely caused by a prematurely terminated query (a `;` in the wrong place). However, that's only the basic issue and injection might still happen when other databases or drivers are used, so better don't use queries like that.

Comment: Yep, not disagreeing, just pointing out that in this specific case - with Oracle - it's not an injection risk; but it's still horrible, and it's better to get into the habit to avoid it being an issue in other DBs, or other clients, and for all the other reasons they are preferable anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Thomas had Already explained what I had in mind, `SQL Injection`
By using bind variables in a , `preparedStatement` we can avoid hacking of Query strings.

```
String queryString = "select keyword,ata_code,ac_model from ata_keywords where keyword = ?1";

PreparedStatement ss = conn.prepareStatement(queryString);

s.setString(1,a1Va2);

rs = ss.executeQuery();
```

Still if you ever wanted your version of Query to work..!
Replace Single Quotes with double single quotes to escape it.

```
rs=ss.executeQuery("select keyword,ata_code,ac_model from ata_keywords where keyword='"+a1Va2.replace("'","''")+"'");
```

Comment: I don't understand the ?1 in queryString.

Comment: it is the bind variable, and u bind your string value to the preparedStatement using setString method.

Comment: As you bind it, what evr input String you bind, it goes as such and hence the query String that we sent to the conn.prepareStement() will not be hacked. Instead , just the value to the ?1 is changed.

Comment: for example a1Va2="FO'S I/C RT SWITCH"; This value is skipped when I try to insert it into database.

Comment: a1Va2.replace("'","''") should work, can you please do this if you wont use preparedStatement

Answer (score 0):

If you know the sequence of records being inserted the problem record will be the record prior to the resuming of successful inserts. 
The sequence of record loading hits an error and causes an implicit rollback of the previous insert statement(s) hence a block of record inserts goes missing.
The error itself looks like a missing bracket.